# SQL: City wise,product wise latest order ID

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have tables:
tbl-city

```
id   city
---------
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

tbl-orders

```
ord_id   product_id   city   date
----------------------------------
1          1             1   12/3/18
2          1             2   13/3/18
3          2             3   12/4/18
4          1             3   14/4/18
5          3             2   11/2/18
6          1             1   15/1/18
7          2             3   15/4/28
```

I need to get all **latest *order Id*** from table `orders`
by ***city wise and product wise*** using **date**

Like this:

```
ord_id   product_id   city
---------------------------
  1           1          1
  2           1          2
  7           2          3
  5           3          2
```

How can I get this?

JOIN/INNER JOIN or any other way?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
select o.*
from orders o
where date = (select max(o1.date)
              from orders o1
              where o1.product_id = o.product_id and o1.city = o.city
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ord_id` increases along with the date (as would be typical), then a simple aggregation works.

```
select product_id, city, max(ord_id)
from tbl_ord
group by product_id, city;
```

Otherwise, the typical method would use `row_number()`:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_id, city order by date desc) as seqnum
      from tbl_ord o
     ) o
where seqnum = 1;
```

In older versions of MySQL, a correlated subquery is a good route.  But if you want exactly one row per product and city, use `ord_id`:

```
select o.*
from tbl_ord o
where o.ord_id = (select o2.ord_id
                  from tbl_ord o2
                  where o2.product_id = o.product_id and o2.city = o.city
                  order by o2.date desc
                  limit 1
                 );
```

Comment: ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by product_id, city order by date desc) as seqnum from tbl_ord' at line 3